# A topological property that holds by countable union/intersection but not by uncountable union/intersection?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

I was wondering about a problem related to regions in differentiable manifolds and I wanted to use an induction. Firstly I didn't notice that in an open set only could be countable connected components, so I was thinking to use an induction in a union with uncountable index.

My question is: Can you give me an example of a topological property that holds by countable union/intersection but not by uncountable union/intersection?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A set is **meager** if it is the countable union of nowhere dense sets. While meager-ness is preserved under countable unions (since countable $\times$ countable = countable), it is not preserved under arbitrary uncountable unions. For example, in $\mathbb{R}$ the whole space is not meager$^*$, but $$\mathbb{R}=\bigcup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\{x\}$$ and every singleton is meager in $\mathbb{R}$.

$^*$This is not obvious! The [Baire category theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem) states that $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology, and many other spaces, is not meager. The Baire category theorem has many applications; I don't think I can write a good summary here, but if you google around (and search on this site) you'll find many uses of it.

---

Relatedly, there is a rich hierarchy of "types of set" beyond just open and closed. For example, we inductively define the classes $\Sigma_\alpha^0$ and $\Pi^0_\alpha$ for $\alpha$ a countable ordinal) as:

- $\Sigma^0_1$= open, $\Pi^0_1$= closed.
- $\Sigma^0_\alpha$ is the set of countable unions of sets, each of which is $\Pi^0_\beta$ for some $\beta<\alpha$; and $\Pi^0_\alpha$ is the set of countable intersections of sets, each of which is $\Sigma^0_\alpha$ for some $\beta<\alpha$.

*(Note that $X$ is $\Sigma^0_\alpha$ iff the complement of $X$ is $\Pi^0_\alpha$. A set is $\Delta^0_\alpha$ if it is both $\Sigma^0_\alpha$ and $\Pi^0_\alpha$.)*

This hierarchy - the [Borel hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_hierarchy) - makes sense for arbitrary spaces. For $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology, and related spaces, it is particularly nice: for example, in $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology we have that every $\Sigma^0_\alpha$ (resp. $\Pi^0_\alpha$) set is $\Sigma^0_\gamma$ (resp. $\Pi^0_\gamma$) whenever $\alpha<\gamma$, and this hierarchy is strict ($\Sigma^0_\gamma$ properly contains $\Sigma^0_\alpha$ for $\gamma>\alpha$). We can of course go beyond the Borel hierarchy (for example, via the [projective hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_hierarchy)) but already the Borel hierarchy contains basically every set of reals you can easily explicitly describe.

Each level of the Borel hierarchy has some amount of closure: e.g. $\Sigma^0_\alpha$ is closed under countable unions but not intersections and $\Pi^0_\alpha$ is closed under countable intersections but not unions. It's a good exercise to show that "countable" is necessary here in general (think about $\alpha=1$). So these provide additional examples.

---

Incidentally, you may find topics in [descriptive set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descriptive_set_theory) of particular interest; [Kechris' book](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387943749) is an excellent introduction.